# Replacing with partial match doesn't work

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I need to replace local path in line of "C:\Program Files\Path" with a remote path "\PC\C$\Program Files\Path". I've built a regexp for that as follows:

```
$path -replace '^(?<ddd>\w):',"\\$($pc.name)\${ddd}`$"
```

The `$path` contains a path retrieved from registry and is known to be a valid path. I'm testing with this path: `C:\Program Files\Path`. For some reason, it fails to retrieve the correct path, missing the drive name. The result is always this: `\\MY_PC\$\Program Files\Path`. Testing with `$matches` return this:

```
if ($path -match '^(?<ddd>\w):') {$matches}
Name                           Value
----                           -----
ddd                            C
0                              C:
```

That is, the regex is matched and `$matches` is properly populated. Stuffing `$1` instead of `${ddd}` didn't work as well. So, what am I doing wrong and how to fix this weird behavior?

PS: I need to preserve both `$($pc.name)` and `${ddd}` in a single replacement regex. Using single quotes in the second regex does a correct replace of drive letter, but suppresses the replacement of PC's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using double quotes for the regex, but to escape the dollar sign that precedes the replacement group name with a backtick. The reason apparently is that the string gets double parsed, first Powershell engine uses dollar signs to do its replacement with evaluated strings, second regex engine uses dollar sign syntax to employ replacement groups. Therefore, an escape of dollar sign is required for the dollar sign to survive first stage parsing and be correctly replaced with matched region. The correct command is as follows:

```
$path -replace '^(?<ddd>\w):',"\\$($pc.name)\`${ddd}`$"
```

On a side note, if you need to use both replacement groups, Powershell evaluated strings and a placement of a dollar sign into the resultant string somewhere but at the end of replacement, you need to use two escaped dollars:

```
$path -replace '1',"`$`$1" # replaces "1" with "$1" literally
```